# fabric: setup is stuck on macOS high Sierra with Xcode 9. How can I skip it and get to create api keys?

Tags: macos, google-fabric

I'm trying to get fabric up and running on macOS 10.13(High Sierra beta), but the macOS tool is stuck on [image: moving folder]. When I move the folder over into my Xcode 9 project, for one, it does not ask me to import but rather the two frameworks just appear where I put them, and the dialog does not move onward and so the api keys are out of reach cause it still wants me to install the frameworks over that tool there.

What do I do? It's probably a bug, where do I report it? Help appreciated!

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Bugs can be reported to support(at)fabric(dot)io, but you can also find the instructions here: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install Doing a build of your app may also help.

Comment: Ah works like a charm! I initially thought the key there is a dummy key, until you pointed me to it and I saw my group name. :). I had to make the frameworks part of my app compilation manually by adding two hooks, that's what triggered the fabric osx program to continue in the setup and work out.

Comment: Glad you're all set, that makes my day. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After drag and dropping the icon, manually add Fabric.framework and Crashlytics.framework in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". Then Fabric App should move to the next step automatically.

[image]